# Building a plugin in Qgis for NDVI calculation using qt creater

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I want to build a Qgis pluin using Qt designer. What elements will I add to the dialogue of plugin in Qt designer. Also I want a python script for that plugin which can manipulate the raster stacked image to calculate ndvi just like we do in Arcmap or ENVI. I don't want to provide Red and NIR layers as input. Instead I want to give raster stacked image as an input and want NDVI map as an output. please help me guys. I want to complete my term project but I don't have good programing skills.

Answer (score 3):

My advice - don't build it in Qt Designer. Instead, implement it as a QGIS processing provider plugin and let QGIS handle creation of the GUI for you.

The other benefit of this approach is that your plugin would then be usable in other processing models - ie the NDVI calculation could become just a single step in a larger model which uses the NDVI as part of a larger calculation.

Comment: I had the same use case and wrote a QGIS Processing script for that, however, couldn't figure out how to work with raster bands for red and NIR inputs (which is also a requirement in the question). Do you know if Processing supports selecting bands from a raster, as it does with fields from vectors?